# How to draw a quotient space

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to understand this exercise:

[image]

What does the author mean? I could find proprieties of this quotient space and everything but I don't know how to draw it, besides that it seems there are a lot of ways to draw this.

I need some clarifications of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sketch of the space:${}$

[image: Picture]

Comment: What are these arrows? thank you!

Comment: @user42912 They're there to indicate the "positive direction", but don't pay attention to them. You're welcome.